# Max files in Laravel 5 logs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I define the maximum number of log files in Laravel 5. I use daily log rotate, and I have "only" 5 log files in storage, I want to have the past 30 days, but I don't know how to do this, and I did not found any clue.

Comment: As far as I know Laravel has no log rotation capability out of the box? It can write log files per day but rotation is your responsibility. If something is deleting log files older than 5 days, it's not Laravel doing it.

Comment: It is handled by monolog and configured in [Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php#L76-L79) but I have no idea how to override that properly to be honest...

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks :). Yes I've read this file, maybe there is no solution for now.

Comment: @Bulk No, I think it's laravel via Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, it's now possible since v5.0.23. You just need to update laravel, and add this in your `config/app.php` file:

```
'log_max_files' => 30
```

**On Laravel 5.6**
You can find `config/logging.php` file:

```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 30, // 0 for unilimitted logs
    ],
```

Comment: Addid this gets my this error 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /home/forge/podcasts.ckiafm.org/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1355'

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: I just tried on a new project, it works. Are you sure this is related?

Comment: To think of it, probably not. I'll have to check later on and keep you posted if I still get the error!

Comment: Use `'log_max_files' => 0` for unlimited log files... See https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13776/files

Comment: The solution is obsolete, for 5.6+ try one below

Answer (score 9):

On Laravel 5.6 open file `config/logging.php` on array daily change: `'days' => 30`

If you want unlimited logs just put 0 instead 30.

Comment: would this work if I'm logging to multiple channels?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function in `ConfigureLogging` or `LogServiceProvider` or so (Since I'm using an old checkout I'm not sure where exactly), something called `useDailyFiles`. In that the file name and maximum file number is set and the default looks something like this:

`$log->useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log', 5);`

Change the last parameter (5) to your desired number of files.

Comment: Any idea where this would normally need to be set? Obviously this can't be changed in the `vendor` directory, because those are all composer packages pulled in from various sources.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in the filename than the rotation days. The filename seems to be configured in the same place here, but does not reference any settings in the config files.

Comment: @Jason you can tweak the setting as you wish and make it read from a custom config file, it can be set in `app/start/global.php`. Note that if you omit the last parameter, there will be no rotation at all and all logs will be kept daily.